# Poisson regression options in python

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to predict count data. In my understanding both standard classification and regression are not well suited for this. A poisson or binomial regression algorithm seems to do the trick.

I am used to doing most of my ML tasks in sklearn. But on this topic I could not find an implementation. Are there any suitable options within the python universe for this?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels

Answer (score 8):

Not quite sklearn but have you tried xgboost?

The [XGBRegressor](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) in xgboost accepts many different [objective functions](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters) including poisson `count:poisson` for count data.

It also plays nicely with sklearn so can be used with grid search, pipelines etc.

Comment: This sounds promising - I will give it a try - though I am not sure when I will have time for this ;).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - i think while interesting as an objective functions this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a regressor that predictions only return integers - and at least when I tried this one it did not do that.

Answer (score 5):

`statsmodels` has you covered.

There aren't a lot of great examples of Poisson regression in the statsmodels API, but if you're happy with GLMs, statsmodels has a [GLM API](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/glm.html) which lets you specify any single-parameter distribution, including Poisson.

Comment: Do you know of any non-linear models that support poisson regression or other methods to predict count data?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "non-linear" in this context?

Comment: Like a neural network, some of the many variants of decision trees, suport vector machines etc.

Comment: Okay. Well, regular Poisson regression is the parameterisation of a Poisson distribution by a linear combination of your predictor variables, so you could replace that linear combination by any non-linear transformation you like. So you could produce a neural network, the output layer of which is a point estimate of a Poisson process. This would, however, be a lot more complicated than regular GLM Poisson regression, and a lot harder to diagnose or interpret. It's probably worth trying a standard Poisson regression first to see if that suits your needs.

Comment: You probably need to write down a loss function which is equal to the negative log likehood of the poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-learn v0.23 now has [`PoissonRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor):

https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_23_0.html#generalized-linear-models-and-poisson-loss-for-gradient-boosting

Answer (score 0):

You can use PoissonRegressor or even RandomForestRegressor in sklearn.
I think you can use common other regressor too, it is not problem, it is base on your evaluation metrics.